# django need help in writing custom field

Tags: python, django, psycopg2

I'm aware that Django do not have a built in model field for postgresql 's custom type "text[]".
After looking at the docs, I'm have a question.

I realized I need to override the db_type method to reflect the 'text[]' data type, but is that all? What do I need to write for the to_python method? I mean, the default value returned is already a list I can use right?

```
class TextArrayField(models.Field):

    def db_type(self,connection):
        return 'text []'
```

using psycopg2.

UPDATE:
I tried creating a table with the above field... but django evolution is throwing an error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'EvolutionOperations'
```

Can anyone enlighten?

Answer (score 0):

`to_python` should mapp the database values to a python objects. For example for DateTimeFieldto_python`turns database`timestamp`into pythons`datatetime` objects.

Comment: since my custom field is only to model custom pgsql data type,  do I ignore both the to_python and get_db_prep_value methods? I realise psycopg2 reads and output the column as list....

Comment: I have no idea. Have you tried using the field without those two methods?

Comment: I've tried, but couldn't create the table because django evolution complains.

Comment: I have never used evolution. How exactly it complains?